# Loading FancyBox image gallery on AJAX website

Tags: php, ajax, dynamic, fancybox

I have created a website using AJAX to load content dynamically however this has caused problems when trying to load a FancyBox image gallery.

If you go to: http://darynjohnson.com/Medical%20Futures/gallery.php - The gallery loads fine as you would expect.

But if you go to another page first then go back to the gallery it doesn't work. 
http://darynjohnson.com/Medical%20Futures/about.php#gallery.php

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is from `gallery.php`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

This triggers on document load, you could try to manually call that function once you load the page from about.php (or whatever other page). Or maybe replace it with:

```
$(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

EDIT: you could do something similar to this in `dynamicpage.js`:

After `$pageWrap.animate({ ... });`, add `$(".fancybox").fancybox();`. This will make sure that the links are ready to open the gallery when clicked.
A better approach could be used to call a function that is defined for each page, or maybe add a condition to check `if (newHash == 'gallery.php')` for example. I hope I'm clearer now.

Comment: You have to try the other way then, calling the fancybox function directly. See the updated answer.